# Imagemagick/GhostScript conversion to jpeg/png ignores the pdf background

Tags: pdf, background, imagemagick, ghostscript

What I am doing is making thumbnails for pdf files (only the first page). I use imagemagick like this (simplified without the resize. It has the same problem):

```
convert mreji.pdf[0] test.jpg
```

The problem is that it just ignores my pdf's background and turns it black. It's not transparent either (if I use png instead of jpg), it's just black. I want to keep the original background color.

Here is the test pdf: http://slides.bg/website/Uploads/Temp/mreji.pdf
And the imagemagick output here: http://slides.bg/website/Uploads/Temp/mreji.jpg
Notice that the background color is replaced with black. I want to keep the original one.

I tried using GhostScript directly

```
gs -sDEVICE=jpeg -sOutputFile=cover.jpg -r72 mreji.pdf
```

Again, the same output. Maybe there is an argument to prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem may be with the "smooth shading" objects in that PDF.

There are a lot (29) Type 2 (Axial Shading), smooth shading objects in the PDF used for the backgrounds and IIRC GhostScript has had problems with these and a number of bug fixes over the years, what version of `gs` are you running?

Easiest solution is to raster the background in whatever created the PDF for this purpose.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I'm running a service which uses user uploaded pdfs, so modifying the pdf is not an option.
I'm running these on Debian stable which had GS 8.62 if I remember correctly. So I upgraded GS from unstable to 8.72 and it seems to work well now. I guess it was a bug, which they fixed.

Comment: @stormbreaker: Glad it was something simple, it's a complex bit of code with the shading provision, the bug fixing on that has been going on *along* time.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the flatten parameter:

```
convert mreji.pdf[0] test.jpg -flatten
```